# (buffer-substring-no-properties) backslash handling

Tags: elisp

Good afternoon. In the text, the record

```
@samp{\}
```

, the code

```
(buffer-substring-no-properties (+ nach 4) (- (point) 4))
```

is captured here this region, at the output of the

```
"@samp{\\}"
```

function. The question is how to get the non-escaped forward slash. Thank you

Comment: There is no forward slash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changes further along the code gave the result, namely, not a correction of the record of the read line, but a change in the insertion of the ill-fated line `"@samp {\\}"` back into the text. The function is presented

```
(defun zamenaOBJ (спсОбктв)
  "Зменить obzx оригиналом"
  (goto-char 1)  
  (while (re-search-forward "[Bb]jkt\\([[:digit:]]\\)+" nil t 1)
    (replace-match (cdr (assoc (downcase (match-string 0)) спсОбктв)) t)))
```

Here is the data at the time of the error (what was received

```
(buffer-substring-no-properties)
```

and saved in the associative list

```
(cdr (assoc (downcase (match-string 0)) спсОбктв))
"@samp{\\}"
```

The error itself

```
(replace-match (cdr (assoc (downcase (match-string 0)) спсОбктв)) t)
```

`Invalid use of ‘\’ in replacement text`

If it was written like this:

```
(replace-match (prin1-to-string (cdr (assoc (downcase (match-string 0)) спсОбктв)) t))
```

все замены по тексту были окружены двойной кавычкой, если же указывался аргумент noescape в t для prin1-to-string:

```
(replace-match (prin1-to-string (cdr (assoc (downcase (match-string 0)) спсОбктв)) t) t)
```

or

```
(replace-match (princ (cdr (assoc (downcase (match-string 0)) спсОбктв)) t))
```

the error came back again

Solved by adding the second argument literal replace-match

```
(replace-match (cdr (assoc (downcase (match-string 0)) спсОбктв)) t t)
```

Answer (score 0):

`"@samp{\\}"` represents the string `@samp{\}`.  It's not different to the original text.

When you ask Emacs to print the return value of `buffer-substring-no-properties` you are seeing the *printed representation* of a string -- which is equivalent to the double-quoted *read syntax* for strings (as you would write it in code) -- in which a single backslash must be escaped with another.

Refer to the elisp manual:

- <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(elisp)Printed Representation`
- <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(elisp)Syntax for Strings`
- <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(elisp)Nonprinting Characters`

Comment: Thank you for your answer and the time spent on this, I made a mistake by posting only a small part of my code. I also read the manual, although the "Nonprinting Characters" and "Syntax for Strings" nodes are not in my manual. Always read the manual carefully! Probably my answer will be off topic, but still. Thank you again.

Comment: Glad you got it figured out.  There's something wrong with your installation if you don't have those info nodes -- those names date back to at least 22.1.  You can always read the manual for the latest release online ([Syntax for Strings](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Syntax-for-Strings.html) and [Nonprinting Characters](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Nonprinting-Characters.html)), but in general it's best to use the in-built manuals for the version of Emacs that you're actually using.